# Javascript: get `this` outside the function

Tags: javascript, function, this

Is it possible to get `this` of a function from outside without calling it in Javascript? I know about the execution context idea, but my logic is, if one can bind `this` to a function, probably there's a way to fetch it. E.g.:

```
var a=function(){}; // let's imagine we have a magic function named `getThisFrom()`
getThisFrom(a); // returns `window` (or nothing, because we haven't used `bind()`)

var obj={};
var b=function(){}.bind(obj);
getThisFrom(b); // returns `obj`
```

Comment: `I know about the execution context idea` - then you should already know that `this` is bound to the function only during the invocation?

Comment: Yes, but before the invocation it must be somewhere in case of `bind()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before you declare function `a` you could save `this` in a variable, i.e. `var self = this;`. Then return `self` inside `a`.

Comment: Probably it's not the most elegant, but the easiest way to go. Or even something like this: `var b=function(){}.bind(obj); b.mythis=obj;` and then look for `b.mythis` (it may be a better solution, especially if the function is passed between different scopes).

Answer (score 0):

`var a = function() { var _b = this; return _b; }`